# Looking for a good geographical library in scala

Tags: gis, scala

I require some geographical features in my package:

- Is this (lat, lon) point inside a polygon (geojson)?
- Create a [buffer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_(GIS)) around a line.
- Production of a geojson from the intersection of two polygons.

I'm using [geotrellis](https://geotrellis.io/) but the learning curve is steep. I'm not sure if it is difficult for me because my lack of good foundations in geographical systems or because there are another library which could help me to do this less complicated (Geotrellis looks very powerful, it's just me).

Answer (score 2):

You might want to look at the [GeoTools](https://geotools.org) Java library for those operations.

1. [Point in Polygon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38693295/java-geotools-check-if-point-is-contained-in-polygon-with-tolerance)
2. [Buffer a line](https://gist.github.com/ianturton/9a7cfee378e7072ec3cd)
3. [Generate GeoJSON](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/298868/convert-list-of-java-objects-with-jts-geom-to-geojson)

Comment: Thanks @iian-turton. Very late but I'm just checking your suggestions... my employer priorities changed until now.